# How to fake the source-port of a TCP packet?

Tags: tcp

Is there an easy way (or is it possible at all) to rewrite a TCP packet as it leaves the machine?
For example if I run

```
telnet binfalse.de 22
```

it will search for an unused port to leave the machine. In this case it's `46576`:

```
root@srv % lsof -i -P -n | grep telnet
telnet    10150   user    3u  IPv4 1159425      0t0  TCP 1.2.3.4:46576->87.118.88.39:22 (ESTABLISHED)
```

But now I want to rewrite these packets to let the server think the requests came from port `1337`, or somewhat like this.  Of course I know that I don't have to expect an answer in my `telnet` session.

**EDIT:**
Of course on `1337` another program is listening, so telling `telnet` to speak through `1337` is no option...

Comment: you should use the word **packet** instead of *package*

Comment: If you want to send IP packets that aren't UDP or a well-formed TCP connection, you need to be root (or have the appropriate capability). Then you could send IP packets that happen to be TCP packets with a bogus source port. But that wouldn't work well, because you'd have to reimplement (a large chunk of) the TCP stack, and you wouldn't go far without being able to receive the ACKs from the other party, which would go to the listening program. Thus you need to re-route the packets to a different port as they come in, with `iptables`.

Comment: Ok, really don't want to establish a connection, I'd be happy if one single packet leaves my machine, and all nodes that have a look into the packet think that it came from `:1337`... I don't care for any answer...

Comment: if that is the case, you should be using a packet-generator like `scapy`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming you are speaking about Linux, `iptables` has a `mangle` table that can do all sorts of crazy things to outgoing TCP traffic.  `iptables` NAT features might help as well, because it really sounds like you want to do "port address translation" or "manual NAT."

Answer (score 6):

If you're really using the `telnet` protocol (or raw tcp streams), you can use `nc -p <source_port>`... `-t` negotiates telnet options.  I have a terminal server below that accepts telnet connections on `tcp/2015` and I will source from `tcp/31415`

```
# Window 1
[mpenning@hotcoffee ~]$ nc -p 31415 -t 192.168.12.117 2015
????????????????

8024-1(config-if-Po2)#
```

To verify...

```
[mpenning@hotcoffee tshark_wd]$ netstat -an | grep 31415
tcp        0      0 192.168.12.236:31415    192.168.12.117:2015     ESTABLISHED
[mpenning@hotcoffee tshark_wd]$
```

This assumes you do not already have a local socket listening on `tcp/31415`... if you already have a local tcp socket bound on the desired port, `iptables` is your only option.

Comment: Unfortunately there is another program listening on this port. so `nc -p` is no option. But nevertheless it can't be bad to list it here, thx ;-)

Comment: @binfalse, help me understand... do you want an established TCP connection, or just to fake some packets from a certain source port (even if another program is listening on that same port)?

Comment: I have a tool listening at port `X`. I want to send some packets (e.g. with telnet or netcat or whatever) from the same machine to a server, but want that server to answer to port `X`. But since there is already something bound to port `X` your command `nc -p X [...]` doesn't work.

Comment: I understand why `nc` won't work... I'm trying to figure out why aren't you just using a packet generator like [scapy](http://www.secdev.org/projects/scapy/)

Comment: Hey thanks a lot, `scapy` works just fine. Never heard of something like that!